# Oracle to select all matched occurrences by a regular expression to one column in one row with separator

Tags: regex, oracle, select, connect-by, regexp-substr

I know to select all matched occurrences by a regular expression to one column in multiple rows as below:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '\+?\d{3,11}', 1, LEVEL) AS substr
FROM (
    SELECT 'Txa233141b Ta233141 Ta233142 Ta233147 Ta233148' AS str FROM DUAL
)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '[^ ]+')) + 1;
```

the result is

```
233141
233141
233142
233147
233148
```

But I want to the result as below, what can I do?

```
233141,233141,233142,233147,233148
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple string functions rather than trying to split the string and the aggregate it:

**Query**:

```sql
WITH test_data ( str ) AS (
  SELECT 'Txa233141b Ta233141 Ta233142 Ta233147 Ta233148' AS str FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TRIM(
         TRAILING ',' FROM
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           str,
           '.*?(\+?\d{3,11}|$)',
           '\1,'
         )
       ) AS replaced_str
FROM   test_data
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | REPLACED_STR                       |
> | :--------------------------------- |
> | 233141,233141,233142,233147,233148 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=19043b800339994a459b1b4e326cf168)*

Answer (score 1):

You can also use listagg on top of your query as following:

```
SELECT listagg(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '\+?\d{3,11}', 1, LEVEL),',') within group (order by 1) AS substr
FROM (
    SELECT 'Txa233141b Ta233141 Ta233142 Ta233147 Ta233148' AS str FROM DUAL
)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '[^ ]+')) + 1;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi, the result is `233141233141233142233147233148`, that is not what I need:)

Comment: Set LISTAGG's second parameter to a comma, e.g. `listagg(regexp_substr(blabla), ', ') within group ...`

Comment: Correct @littlefoot